# column with two dimensions in postgres is deprecated?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create table with .sql ... but errors:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."User" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
  schedule INTEGER[2][2]
);
```

error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "schedule"
LINE 4: schedule INTEGER[2][2]
^
FAILURE
```

Comment: Debugging tip: if you have a theory about the cause of the error, try making the smallest change that would fix it if you were right - in this case, changing `INTEGER[2][2]` to `INTEGER[2]` or just `INTEGER`. If the error persists, you're looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `,` after `name` column. Try the following

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."User" (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  schedule INTEGER[2][2]
);
```

Comment: I am very distracted, but it generated a 1D array I think.